# How to resize UWP app columns, the same as the latest Windows Mail app update does?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

The Mail app now has the ability to use custom resizing by simply dragging with the mouse (a feature that should have been there since day 1). I never heard of any new APIs or anything that allows this. Can someone enlighten me? I would love to use this feature in my app.

Comment: If this answer works then consider Mark as Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [GridSplitter](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/GridSplitter/) control from UWPCommunityToolkit.

Here is a sample Code. Source: [GridSplitter](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/GridSplitter/)

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="11"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="11"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!--Column Grid Splitter-->
    <controls:GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="11" ResizeBehavior="BasedOnAlignment" ResizeDirection="Auto" Background="Gray" Foreground="White" FontSize="13">
        <controls:GridSplitter.Element>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="&#xE784;" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets">
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </controls:GridSplitter.Element>
    </controls:GridSplitter>

    <!--Row Grid Splitter-->
    <controls:GridSplitter Foreground="White" Grid.Row="1" ResizeBehavior="BasedOnAlignment" ResizeDirection="Auto" Background="Gray" Height="11" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="13">
        <controls:GridSplitter.Element>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="&#xE76F;" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets">
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </controls:GridSplitter.Element>
    </controls:GridSplitter>
</Grid>
```